# Eigen spline interpolation: zero derivatives at ends

Tags: c++, interpolation, eigen

I need to interpolate a tabled function s.t. the resulting spline has zero derivatives at ends of interval. I wrote the example using `InterpolateWithDerivatives` function, but the resulting spline doesn't cross the given points:

```
typedef Eigen::Spline<double,1> Spline1d;
typedef Eigen::SplineFitting<Spline1d> Spline1dFitting;

void test_spline()
{
    Eigen::VectorXd x(5);
    Eigen::VectorXd y(5);
    x << 0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0;
    y << 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0;

    Eigen::VectorXd derivatives(2);
    derivatives << 0., 0.;

    Eigen::VectorXi indices(2);
    indices << 0, x.size() - 1;

    Spline1d const& spline = Spline1dFitting::InterpolateWithDerivatives(
        y.transpose(), derivatives.transpose(), indices, 3, x);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++ i)
        std::cout << "must be 0: " << spline(x(i)) - y(i) << std::endl;
}
```

While without fixing derivatives it works well:

```
void test_spline_2()
{
    Eigen::VectorXd x(5);
    Eigen::VectorXd y(5);
    x << 0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0;
    y << 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0;

    Spline1d const& spline2 = Spline1dFitting::Interpolate(y.transpose(), 3, x);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++ i)
        std::cout << "must be 0: " << spline2(x(i)) - y(i) << std::endl;
}
```

Is something wrong here?

Comment: Whit is the output in the two cases?

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem yesterday. Unfortunately there is indeed a bug in eigen. As pointed out by Andreas, the vector b was not initialized properly.

As I do not have time to track the bug in eigen, I am posting my patch here so that it may help in case someone is having the same issue.

```
--- /original/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/Splines/SplineFitting.h  2018-09-24 10:13:26.281178488 +0200
+++ /new/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/Splines/SplineFitting.h   2018-09-26 14:59:13.737373531 +0200
@@ -381,11 +381,12 @@

 DenseIndex row = startRow;
 DenseIndex derivativeIndex = derivativeStart;
+
 for (DenseIndex i = 1; i < parameters.size() - 1; ++i)
 {
   const DenseIndex span = SplineType::Span(parameters[i], degree, knots);

-      if (derivativeIndices[derivativeIndex] == i)
+      if (derivativeIndex < derivativeIndices.size() && derivativeIndices[derivativeIndex] == i)
   {
     A.block(row, span - degree, 2, degree + 1)
       = SplineType::BasisFunctionDerivatives(parameters[i], 1, degree, knots);
@@ -395,8 +396,9 @@
   }
   else
   {
-        A.row(row++).segment(span - degree, degree + 1)
+        A.row(row).segment(span - degree, degree + 1)
           = SplineType::BasisFunctions(parameters[i], degree, knots);
+        b.col(row++) = points.col(i);
   }
 }
 b.col(0) = points.col(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled over the same issue. There seems to be a bug in Eigen.

First example:

```
must be 0: 0
must be 0: 7.54792e+168
must be 0: 1.90459e+185
must be 0: 7.54792e+168
must be 0: 0
```

Second example:

```
must be 0: 0
must be 0: 0
must be 0: 0
must be 0: 0
must be 0: 0
```

The right hand side vector `b` does not get filled properly in `InterpolateWithDerivatives` (SplineFitting.h).

When calling `lu.solve` in your example, `b` is

```
0.0
0.0
1.0
1.90459157797e+185
2.06587336741e+161
0.0
0.0
```

Comment: @maksim-surov did you fix in the eigen repository? I cannot see your change.
If you fixed in your own copy, can you please post how to fix it?

Comment: i fixed my own repo. i can publish my changes in github if u need.

Comment: I did the same and posted my solution (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tested this, and it is fixed in the latest version of Eigen.